# Someone please explain how to get the FAx and FEx because both support are pin.. I only got the FAy and FEy

Tags: structural-analysis

[image] Can someone explain how to get the Fx for the support A and E

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your actual work. What did you do to find $F_y$?

Answer (score 1):

As always, let's start with the global equilibrium equations:

$$\begin{align}
\sum F_x &= A_x + E_x = 0 \\
\therefore A_x &= -E_x \\
\sum F_y &= A_y + E_y - 3\times40 = 0 \\
\therefore A_y &= 120 - E_y \\
\sum M_A &= 5E_x - 40(5 + 10 + 15) = 0 \\
\therefore E_x &= 240\text{ kN} \\
\therefore A_x &= -240\text{ kN}
\end{align}$$

So that's the horizontal reactions, trivially found by using global equilibrium equations.

For completeness, we can also directly find the vertical components since $E$ is only connected to one truss member, therefore $E$'s resultant reaction must be parallel to that member.

$$\begin{align}
\dfrac{E_y}{E_x} &= \dfrac{5}{15} \\
\therefore E_y &= \dfrac{E_x}{3} = 80\text{ kN} \\
\therefore A_y &= 40\text{ kN}
\end{align}$$